# Android--Recyclerview inside recyclerview (Food and extra)

Tags: listview, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a problem and hope e.o help me!

I have a fragment include list food, each food have list extra (like image)==> List food is managed by AdapterFood==> AdapterFood manage item food and list extra.
When I removed item, adapter updated data (include food and extra).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULHuP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your view holder when you call the click listener make sure you delete it like this

```
deleteView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            int pos=getAdapterPosition();
            mArrayList.remove(pos);// List that contains the data
           notifyItemRemoved(pos);

           }
```

Comment: but extra status existed. #I2S0215WMAB08 how to update total when checking extra